# Cascade delete in Entity Framework database first

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I want to make Cascade delete in ASP.NET 4.6.1 MVC Project,

It is database first project, but cascade delete not working.

I get this error:

> The operation failed: The relationship could not be changed because one or more of the foreign-key properties is non-nullable.
>   When a change is made to a relationship, the related foreign-key property is set to a null value.
>   If the foreign-key does not sup...

I have two tables:

Category:

```
Category_ID
Category_Name
```

Article:

```
Article_ID
Article_Name
Article_Content
Category_ID   which is Foreign key
```

That is my code to delete:

```
var context = new DbContext();

Category category = context.Category.First(c => c.CategoryID == catID);

if (category != null)
{
    context.Category.Remove(category);
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: You need to show us your table/code, so we could help you. But the error message is quite obvious, you have a foreign key relationship which is not nullable.  So if you delete the record the foreign key relationship becomes invalid.

Comment: I edit my question, but why the cascade delete not working

Comment: But i want to delete all articles related to specific category when i delete that category !!!

Comment: any body here ...

Comment: are you using EF code first? Could you please show how you are creating your model?

Comment: No, it is Database First, my question title is Database First

Comment: Can you change your DB schema? Like adding "ON DELETE CASCADE" for your FK?

Comment: Thank you for your interest, but from where to change it? sorry, i am newbie, change it in database then update the model ??

Comment: @mustafa check the keys folder under your table folder.

Answer (score 0):

Update: for db first, go to the properties of the entity that should be cascaded and find the property End2 On Delete. Set this to cascade.

For code first:
You can define the relationships you want to cascade delete in your mapping. In your data context, override OnModelCreating and define your custom mapping.

I have not tested the code but it should look something like this:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Article>()
            .HasRequired(a => a.Category)
            .WithMany(c => c.Articles)
            .HasForeignKey(a => CategoryId)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete();

    }
```

The idea is to call `WillCascadeOnDelete()` on your mapping.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696319(v=vs.113).aspx

Comment: Is that solution for database first or code first? Question specifies db first.

Comment: This is for code first. For db first, there are options in the visual studio designer to set this property. I’ll update the answer

Comment: The questioner is asking cascade delete in EF Database-first but the answer is for code-first approach!

Comment: @PureSilence NO! The first paragraph in the answer is for db first. It also provides the code first answer after that

Comment: Yes, you're right! Anyway, it was a good answer and thanks for noticing me!

Comment: Not the most useful answer unfortunately. There are already questions about code first.
The note about data first at the top isn't enough for an answer either.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using database-first approach, first you need to set Delete Rule for the relationship to Cascade in the database.

Then update your EF designer in your program. Now the following code will delete the Category object and all its Articles:

```
if (dbContext.Entry(categoryObj).State == System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Detached)
                dbContext.Categories.Attach(categoryObj);

dbContext.Categories.Remove(categoryObj);

dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: How do you "Set the Delete Rule for the relationship to Cascade in the database"?

Comment: You can set the current foreign key constraint between 2 tables to on Delete Cascade rule simply in ssms (SQL Server Management Studio) and if you like to do it by T-SQL script then first you have to drop the current foreign key constraint by ALTER command and then: ALTER TABLE Article ADD CONSTRAINT Category_Article 
FOREIGN KEY (Category_ID) REFERENCES Category(Category_ID) ON DELETE CASCADE;

Comment: That might be a good addition to the answer